# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 using latest Chromium v116.0

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

Trying to run Selenium with Chromium (through ChromeDriverManager) on a Linux machine.

Error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
```

Chromium info:

```
$ chrome --version
Chromium 116.0.5826.0
$ which chrome
/usr/local/bin/chrome
```

Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromiumService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.core.utils import ChromeType

chromium_driver = ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromiumService(chromium_driver))
driver.get("http://www.justinbieber.sucks")
driver.quit()
```

The error message makes it obvious that this is a version/compatibility issue (between Chromium and ChromeDriver), but there doesn't seem to be a ChromeDriver for Chromium 16.0 yet. Also, I can't for the love of God find a download link for Chromium 14. ChromeDriverManager is not helping a lot either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114. LATEST\_RELEASE\_115 doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76913935/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-this-version-of-chromedri)

Comment: @Gugu72 You are linking this question to another question which was asked almost 2 monts later. Ideally yhe later should have been a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Yes, excepted the answer given below is not the best answer (negative score: even if it was accepted, while downgrading chrome browser works it is not a viable solution)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
```

...implies that there is a version incompatibility between [chromium](/questions/tagged/chromium) and [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) version.

---

### This usecase

The latest ChromeDriver being [v**114.0.5735.90**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=114.0.5735.90/) you have to downgrade the Chromium browser version accordingly.

---

### Solution

To download, install and use a specific version of Chrome / Chromium on Linux you need to follow the relevant steps from the [**Download Chromium**](https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium/) page:

> Downloading old builds of Chrome / Chromium Let's say you want a build
> of Chrome 44 for debugging purposes. Google does not offer old builds
> as they do not have up-to-date security fixes.
>
> However, you can get a build of Chromium 44.x which should mostly
> match the stable release.
>
> Here's how you find it:
>
> Look in https://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/search/label/Stable
> updates for the last time "44." was mentioned. Loop up that version
> history ("44.0.2403.157") in the Position Lookup In this case it
> returns a base position of "330231". This is the commit of where the
> 44 release was branched, back in May 2015.* Open the continuous builds
> archive Click through on your platform (Linux/Mac/Win) Paste "330231"
> into the filter field at the top and wait for all the results to XHR
> in. Eventually I get a perfect hit:
> https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html?prefix=Mac/330231/
> Sometimes you may have to decrement the commit number until you find
> one. Download and run!
>
> - As this build was made at 44 branch point, it does not have any commits merged in while in beta.
>
> Typically that's OK, but if you need a true build of "44.0.2403.x"
> then you'll need to build Chromium from the 2403 branch. Some
> PortableApps/PortableChromium sites offer binaries like this, due to
> security concerns, the Chrome team does not recommend running them.